# How to use changes of a component in an another open tab?

Tags: angular

In my project in Angular 5 when user clicks on a link a new tab of project opens then something changes in the new page. Now how can I use these changes for the first tab? I used Subject and Observable and save the variable for the first component. The code goes into the first component but the first tab doesn't change, because all of these happenings are in second tab. I want when I go to the first tab again the changes related to this component done.
I don't know how to solve it, please help if you know.
Thank you in advanced...

Comment: check routing and navigation section here. [routing](https://angular.io/guide/router). and use services for communication between components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its not applicable to a subject to be fired in one tab and catch it in another tab,
so you can simply use the storage change event as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', storageChanged);

// here listen to the changes
storageChanged(event) {
  // your code
}
```

in another tab, when something changed, you can add it to the storage, then it will be cached in the first event listener

```
  localStorage.setItem('crossTabTest',data);
```

this approach is used when something not related to data fetched from server side, in such case, you probably will use Socket.io to receive the changes.

---------------------- New Edit Section ----------------------

First Component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
      const a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('crossTabTest'));
      localStorage.removeItem('crossTabTest');
      console.log('Changed Value = ', a);
    });
  }
```

Second Component

```
localStorage.setItem('crossTabTest', JSON.stringify({continue: true}));
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. where can I put the first block of code in first component? In ngOnInit or else where?

Comment: the first block,
in the component ngOnInit method, in the component which the change will affect it.

the second block where the change occurs.

Comment: so I think the problem is still remains. because ngOnInit of first page render at the beginning and after this the second page opens and some changes happen. and exactly after these changes I want to use them in page 1.

Comment: ngOnInit(): void {
        window.addEventListener('storage', this.storageChanged());           }      storageChanged() {
        const a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('crossTabTest'));
        console.log(a);
        localStorage.removeItem('crossTabTest');
        return a;
    }    this is my code in first component and in second component is:           localStorage.setItem('crossTabTest', JSON.stringify({continue: true}));

Comment: I made an edit to the answer, i added the code you need